Site Going Live
I have hired a Marketing Company to "rebuild" my company's site and advertise it. There is an issue trying to get the site to go live and I am not allowing them to do anything until I know exactly how to do this properly. *
A little background:

I had a WordPress site built by a 3rd Party company that is also my host server.
I bought the domain name that is pointing to that company's server from NameCheap.

This is where it gets suspicious, or the Marketing company does not exactly know what they are doing -

First, they wanted me to change hosting server to "their server" which I did not allow.
Then, to get the site live, they are asking for me to give them access to my DNS Records to add an "A record," which we all know is the IP address that is associated with the domain name of my company. Thus, even if I give them access to my DNS Records, the only access I can give them is my NameCheap account (where I bought the domain name), and not the company that is hosting my site, correct?

Now, they "rebuilt" the site on some temporary url and are trying to get it live. My question is, How are they going to do this when I will not give them access to my DNS Records? Do they have to use a different IP address and if so, does that not change the ownership of my company? And what exactly are they going to "add" to my DNS records if I will not allow them to change my host server?
Also, if hypothetically, the only option is to create a new A Record IP address, isn't that going to change the ownership of my domain name? One solution that I thought that I can personally do is just rebuild the site myself copying exactly the content and format that they did (because they rebuilt it for SEO optimization for the Marketing Campaign which is what I paid for) and thus, since I will do this on the backend, and the site is already live, the problem is solved. Thanks in advance! John
I have paused everything and will not allow them to do anything until I know that this is being done correctly.

I empathize with your situation, but unfortunately this Q&A forum isn't suited for the individualized one-on-one guidance that something like this really calls for. My advice is to not give passwords to your NameCheap account to anyone you don't fully trust, because there is potential for damage. At the same time, none of their behavior you described sounds suspicious to me, assuming you hired them to replace your current web host and host your website for you. Your understanding of the basics seems somewhat confused, so I might recommend hiring someone trusted to help you unravel this.

On the other hand if you did not hire them to replace your current web host and host your website for you, it's possible there could be a misunderstanding between the two parties. In any case, I don't believe we would be able to get a clear understanding of this situation in this Q&A format.

Thanks. In the contract, there was nothing mentioned about changing host server, and they did not tell me they intended to do so. Why did they not just do the site rebuild for SEO optimization on my current site? One option I just came up with is for them and even me to rebuild it again exactly as they did on the current site that is already live and pointing to my host server. However, if I find that they can retain the domain name I own for my company and point it to "their server", then I would consider this. But again, why do they need to do this? I have already contacted my lawyers.

@MaximillianLaumeister  I think this is on topic here (although it is rather long winded).    It seems to me the OP does not understand the relationship between Registrar, DNS and Web Server - and once he understands this he will be able to navigate the issue.  This is the kind of thing we can easily answer here.

Hopefully this question is reopened and I can provide an answer, but in the Interim - To get a website working there are multiple moving parts which can be separated - and you seem to not be aware of some -   In general you have your registrar (from whom you purchase your domain), your nameserver which can be seperate to your registrar, but are often combined, and then your web host.  The point being that in cases where your registrar is not your dns provider you can give your hosting provider access to modify your DNS without giving them access to your registrar...

That said, it does sound like your marketing company is incompetent or duplicitous.  I have seen so called web devs say that hosting can continue where it is - only to require it to be shifted to their hosting at the end of the project because they built it in a proprietary framework.     If they are using Wordpress, you should be able to back up the site and then restore it to your current web hosting provider yourself  - of-course, if you paid them to do this, they should be able to do so with only the credentials to your web hosting account.

If the only option is to create a new A record address (more likely replace the old one), you should be able to do this yourself - and just co-ordinate the actual time of the changeover with them.

There are lots of ways of migrating a website  - many from within Wordpress using free plugins - have a look at updraft and Backup Buddy among other solutions.

Thanks everyone for your help. @davidgo My main concern is that this is done properly and something ridiculous does not happen that causes a huge mess. I do not mind changing host servers if it either enhances the site or keeps it the same. And, yes, they want to change hosting probably because it fits into their "process." I am going to talk with all of them tomorrow. *One thing, it seems like my nameserver is from my webhost, it's certainly not from my registrar, Namecheap. Again, thanks for your help, I'll get this resolved in a few days, John

Either there is a severe breakdown in communications here or the company who redesigned your site are grossly incompetent.

First, they wanted me to change hosting server to "their server" which I did not allow

Was it explicitly agreed that you would NOT be using their hosting when you commissioned the work?

How are they going to do this when I will not give them access to my DNS Records?

Easy - they just set it up under a different hostname. With some CMS (notably Wordpress) the hostname is baked into the config and content. While its trivial to rewrite the hostname used in HTTP headers on a reverse proxy, changing the content (html, javascript, css) is a LOT more difficult. Essentially, operating the service under a different name means rewriting the config and the content. Maybe they have a solution for that. However that does not change the fact that:

(I infer) you specified you would be hosting the service - they have not delivered

For testing prior to release they can easily add an entry in their local hosts file to override DNS, or use a split DNS

For SSL, its a little more tricky, but still straightforward to operate the service elsewhere with a redirection mechanism like 2


Oh, and BTW using an A record for your canonical hostname is not good practice.
They can't take control of your site with you giving them control over DNS (or changing the DNS under their instructions). If they were told at the start they would not be hosting the site, then they don't need to do this.
We're only guessing at their side of the story. You need to talk to them.
